# How do i change url of site logo on sevral sharepoint sites or All my sharepoint sites?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

Is there a way to change the urls of site-logo manually on my sharepoint sites?
as in when i click on the logo i want to be redirected to a certain site.

With code vs without code ?

If I were to do it with code on Visual Studio 2013 how do i go about it from scratch? like how do i import the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some solutions to this. I'll give you one *without* code:

Open up your masterpage either with SPD on your Sitecollection or in your Hive folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS
```

Now jump to the *SiteLogo* section.

Replace the `<SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink>` tag with a `<SharePoint:SPLinkButton>` tag. the SPLinkbutton has a `NavigationUrl` property, which lets you define the url of the link, unlike the standard SPSimpleSiteLink, which just points to the root site of your current site.

It should now look something like this:

```
//replace NavigateUrl with your desired link
<SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~sitecollection/" CssClass="ms-siteicon-a" ID="vaksjgvbsivwe8f69h39vh">
</Sharepoint:SPLinkbutton>
```

*Don't just copy & paste this. You need to keep your ID!*